# HTML5 Web DB Security

Tags: security, html, offlineapps

I'm looking into an offline web app solution using HTML5.
The functionality is everything I need BUT the data stored can be directly queried right in the browser and therefore completely unsecure!

Is there anyway to encrypt/hide so that the data is secure?

Thanks,
D.

Comment: Please see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976046/html5-client-side-data-encryption-what-are-my-options/6686558#6686558

Answer (score 20):

There are two concerns to local storage in HTML5 -

1. One website reading offline data that another website has stored in a users browser
2. An end user querying your websites offline data directly

For 1, browsers enforce the same-domain restrictions to localStorage (or the sqllite database support that safari has), so other websites won't have access to the data that you store. However, do remember that if your site has XSS vulnerabilities, it would be possible to steal the data.

For 2, you can't prevent it. Its just like a cookie - the user can chose to view/delete/modify it.

Encryption of data is possible (see http://farfarfar.com/scripts/encrypt/), but pointless. You cannot have a single, global key/password - because an attacker can easily figure the key from javascript code. Using a user-entered password to encrypt/decrypt is possible, but client-side encryption libraries aren't mature or tested well enough. There are likely tons of way to break it.

So, for now atleast, don't store sensitive data in localStorage.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/ is mature crypto library safe for use in client-side code (though it uses GWT)

Answer (score 5):

You can also see an [article on this concern](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/04/13/towards-more-secure-client-side-data-storage/) by the author of the HTML5 SecureStore Porposal

Answer (score 2):

If you're storing data on the user's computer, the user can always read it, no matter how much you encrypt it [assuming you aren't using a hash...]

Sensitive data goes on the server-side, always.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the encrypted data can only be decrypted with a key that you have to get from the server every time (ie., it's not stored anywhere in JS or on the page), and if the server only provides the key when user is securely authenticated, then between user's legitimate sessions the locally encrypted data is secure.

Comment: Hashing is not encryption either.

Comment: @drogon sure but something is better than nothing