# Is there a secure way to store data locally with HTML5 or Flash AS3?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, encryption, local-storage

I'm looking for a HTML5 or Flash AS3 equivalent to Adobe Air's [encrypted local storage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e31.html) to store sensitive data such as OAuth token and passwords locally.
I found *local storage* for HTML5 and the [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) for Flash but none of them are encrypted.
Is there a secure way to store data locally from either HTML5 or Flash AS3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing the encryption/decryption server side and store the encrypted string values within *local storage*. This way you can setup your own encryption standards.

Comment: Interesting, can you please give me some more input on it? Is there a best practice available for it?

Comment: I'm not aware of any best practices for it, but after doing some digging, I found a couple questions about it. [HTML5 Web DB Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642043/html5-web-db-security), [Client Side Data Encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976046/html5-client-side-data-encryption-what-are-my-options/6686558#6686558), [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/). The last one is interesting, I may consider using on my own projects.